# Is there any way to use Model.find() Querie with populated field filter in node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm using Model.find() Querie like this

```
const model = require("../../models/product");

module.exports = async(filters) => {
        let data = Object.values(filters.data)[0]
        let field = Object.keys(filters.data)[0];
        const regex = new RegExp(escapeRegex(data), 'gi');
        return await model.find({ $or: [{
                [field]: regex }] }).populate("division_id").populate("type_id").populate("category_id").exec()
    }
    //$or:[ {'_id':objId}, {'name':param}, {'nickname':param} ]
function escapeRegex(text) {
    return text.replace(/[-[\]{}()*+?.,\\^$|#\s]/g, "\\$&");
};
```

#### Filter

In filter i'm sending { data : { name : "a" } }

which is giving all products with name started with "a" which is Ok !

but now i want to get filter result which have specific division

response incudes only that specific division product

#### Product Schemas

> _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,

> division_id: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Division', required: [true, "Product Division Id is Required"] },

> name: { type: String, required: [true, "Product Name is Required"] },

#### Division Schemas

> _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,

> name:{ type: String, required: "Division Name is Required" },

Answer (score 0):

Try using the example in here: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#query-conditions

So I assume it should be something like this:

```
return await model.find({
  $or: [
    { [field]: regex } // By the way, if it's the only query in $or, you don't need $or
  ],
}
.populate({
  path: "division_id",
  match: { _id: <ObjectId> }
})
.populate("type_id")
.populate("category_id")
.exec();
```

First `.populate` will be extended a bit to include specific match. In there, you can pass `_id` (as an example, or `name`, based on your schema) to match specific division.

Comment: thanks for your response ... but  i'm still getting error "Cannot read property '_id' of null"

Comment: @user16452247 That must on some other line because my code doesn't have nullable object